# Ajax post formdata net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have 2 similar JS functions:

1)

```
$(area).on('click','#copy',function (e) {
    //var images=[];
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this=$(this);
    var $gal=$this.closest('.gal_insertion_new');
    var id=$gal.attr('gal_id');
    var $copy=$gal.find("#copy");
    $copy.attr("disabled", true);
    var copy_to=$gal.find('#copy_to').val();
    var row_paste=$gal.find('#row_copy_to');
    var formData=new FormData();
    var row_p_l=row_paste.length;
    var row_p_v=row_paste.val();
    console.log(row_p_v);
    if (copy_to=='') {
        alert('Заполните id галереи');
        return;
    }
    formData.append('gal_id',id);
    if ($gal.find('input:checked').length<1){
        alert('Выберите хотябы одну картинку');
        return;
    }
    $.each($gal.find('input:checked'),function (i,item) {
        formData.append(i,$(item).attr('image_id'));
    });
    formData.append('what','copy_images');
    formData.append('where',copy_to);
    if (row_p_l>0) {
        if (row_p_v==''){
            alert('Заполните номер ряда');
            return;
        }
        formData.append('where_row',row_p_v);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        //alert(response);

            if (response[0]==0) {
                alert(response[1]);
            } else if (response[0]==1) {
                alert(response[1]);
            } else if (response[0]==2) {
                alert(response[1]);
            } else {
                if ($('div[gal_id=' + copy_to + ']').length > 0) {
                    if (row_p_l > 0) {
                        response.forEach(function (item,i) {
                            $('.row_item_img_preview[image_id=' + item['id'] + ']').attr('src', item['path']);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('.img_previews[gallery_id=' + copy_to + ']').append(response);
                    }
                    alert('Скопировано');
                }
            }
        $copy.attr("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

2)

```
$(area).on('click','#delete_selected_images',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete');
    var $this=$(this);
    //$this.attr("disabled", true);
    var $gal=$this.closest('.gal_insertion_new');
    var id=$gal.attr('gal_id');
    var formData=new FormData();
    //console.log(row_p_v);
    formData.append('gal_id',id);
    if ($gal.find('input:checked').length<1){
        alert('Выберите хотябы одну картинку');
        return;
    }
    $.each($gal.find('input:checked'),function (i,item) {
        formData.append(i,$(item).attr('image_id'));
        console.log(item);
    });
    formData.append('what','delete_images');
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log('delete2');
        /*
        console.log(response);
        //alert(response);
        $.each($gal.find('input:checked'),function (i,item) {
            $(item).remove();
        });
        */
        $this.attr("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

The first one works perfect, but the second one gives me net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.
I'm using laravel, PHP 7.0.1, currently running on OpenServer.
The use of debugger gives nothing, but the understanding that the error is somewhere in the framework, or in my script.

Using json is not an option, cause of my PHP code...

Comment: disable APCU config in php.ini.

Comment: can't find this option neither in php nor apache